# Airflow task dont start but stuck on "running"

Tags: airflow

I'm completely new to Airflow, and I really struggle getting a very simple test DAG to run:

```py
from airflow import DAG
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
from airflow.utils.dates import days_ago
from airflow.operators.bash import BashOperator


default_args ={
"owner":"airflow",
"depends_on_past":False,
"retries":0,
"email": ["my_email@hotmail.com"],
"email_on_failure":True
}


dag = DAG(dag_id="create_test_folder", 
default_args=default_args,
start_date = days_ago(1),
catchup=False,
schedule_interval="@once")

start = BashOperator(task_id="start",dag=dag,bash_command="mkdir ~/airflow/test_folder")
end = BashOperator(task_id="end",dag=dag,bash_command="date")
start>>end
```

If I open the webserver and press "trigger DAG" it is stuck under "running" and seems to never start (the tree-diagram says "not started")
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your DAG isn't running because it's paused. You need to unpause it.

[image]

Note that you can avoid this issue by using `is_paused_upon_creation` this flag specifies if the dag is paused when created for the first time.
If the dag exists already, this flag will be ignored.

```
dag = DAG(dag_id="create_test_folder",
          default_args=default_args,
          start_date=days_ago(1),
          catchup=False,
          schedule_interval="@once",
          is_paused_upon_creation=False
          )
```

You can also set up it globally in `airflow.cfg` or by setting env var: [AIRFLOW__CORE__DAGS_ARE_PAUSED_AT_CREATION](https://airflow.apache.org/docs/apache-airflow/stable/configurations-ref.html#dags-are-paused-at-creation)

Comment: That is, what we call a rookie-mistake. I thought it got triggerd anyway, eventhough it was paused, since you "ask to trigger"

Comment: @CutePoison see my edit. Added explanations how to avoid it in the future